# Confusing about parameter passing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload=>  
        <button></button>
        <script>
        function give_show(value) {
            return function() {
                console.log(value);
            }
        }

        var button_element =document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        button_element.addEventListener('load',give_show('bong!'),false)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code works. in console I got:

```
bong!
```

However, if I change this part:

```
function give_show(value) {
    return function() {
        console.log(value);
    }
```

to

```
function give_show(value) {
    return function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
```

I got something like

```
mouse.event
```

What's causing that to happen?

FYI: I use Safari console to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Nested functions have access to everything defined in the scope in which they are created.  So:

```
function give_show(value){
  return function(){ console.log(value); }
}
```

when you reference `value` in the nested function the variable defined in `give_show` is in scope and is used.

However, when you do this:

```
function give_show(value){
  return function(value){ console.log(value); }
}
```

you are returning a function that takes an argument `value`, so that variable name hides the one defined by `give_show`.

---

To make what's happening in the second case more obvious, this code does exactly the same thing, without hiding the `value` variable from the outer scope:

```
function give_show(value){
  return function(event){ console.log(event); }
}
```

The `console.log` method is using the argument passed to your returned function, and is completely ignoring the value passed to `give_show`.  This is why you're getting 'mouse.event' and not 'bong!' in your second case - event handlers are passed the event as their argument.

Comment: @gdoron: `'bong!'` is the initial value passed to the `give_show()` function and assigned to the `value` parameter. So the function that `give_show()` returns will always have access to that parameter. :)

Comment: You're using the returned function as the event handler for the button.  Event handlers are passed the event as an argument, so that's the `value` you're getting in your function.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because at the time that you're calling `console.log(value);` the `value` variable is referring to the parameter of the most inner function. This parameter overrides the value of the parameter you passed into `give_show` because it has the same name. When that function is called as a result of a click event, the browser will pass the actual click event object as the first parameter into that inner function, which is why you see `mouse.event` when you do `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize it this way...

```
function give_show(value) { // <-- 1. You passed 'bong!'

    return function(value) { // <-- 2. Browser passes the Event object <--------+
//                                                                              |
        console.log(value); // <-- 3. Will use the nearest "value" it finds ----+
   };
}
```

So the returned function is used as the event handler. When an event occurs, the browser pass an `Event` object to that function. Since you named the parameter `value`, `console.log` will use that.

---

If you didn't give the name `value` to the handler function, the next `value` would be the one defined in your `give_show` function...

```
function give_show(value) { // <-- 1. You passed 'bong!' <----------------------+
//                                                                              |
    return function(foo) {   // <-- 2. Browser passes the Event object          |
//                                                                              |
        console.log(value); // <-- 3. Will use the nearest "value" it finds ----+
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change `load` for `click` on listners and add `console.log` before return internal function:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <button></button>
        <script>
            function give_show(value) {
                console.log(value);

                return function(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }               
            }

            var button_element =document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
            button_element.addEventListener('click',give_show("bong!"),false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

confusion is when `give_show` is passed to `addEventListner`. In example `give_show` run before you click in button and `Bong!` is write on console. The `addEventListner` only recognizes function:

```
function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

and event(click) pass to `value` the position of clicked by mouse. This is same to make this:

```
button_element.addEventListener('click',function(value) {
                                            console.log(value);
                                        },
                                 false);
```

If you suppress `value` parameter `value` used is from passed to `give_show` function.